# How would I say "intervention-based" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

The sentence I'm translating refers to "intervention-based treatment for non-violent young adults".

What would a good Spanish version be?

I bet there's something better than

> tratamiento basado en la intervención por los jóvenes adultos que no están violento

Or

> tratamiento basado en la intervención por los jóvenes adultos no violento

I wonder if it would be clear to say

> tratamiento intervención por los jóvenes adultos no violento

The context is:

> We have enacted new programs for intervention-based treatment for non-violent young adults.

Comment: El término que buscas es "intervencionista"

Comment: It would be helpful to see the whole sentence.  Context helps tremendously.  When you see the whole context you can often find words that can be omitted.

Comment: @aparente001 I have updated the question to include context.

Comment: Hemos implementado nuevos tratamientos intervencionistas para adultos jóvenes no violentos.  Do you see what I mean?  You can rearrange things in more comfortable, natural ways, once you look at the gestalt of the whole thing.

Comment: @aparente001 yes I see. That’s quite nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first part is absolutely right. It would be "basado en la intervención".

The mistakes are in the second part.

- Remember that "for" is "para", not "por", most of the times.
- Adults is plural, so the adjective must be plural.
- Being violent is something that defines the person, not a state. Use "ser", unless you want to say that "they are violent that day, or something similar".
- The treatment is directed to "young adults" in general, not "the" young adults we might have introduced before. Then remove the article "los".

> Tratamiento basado en la intervención **para** jóvenes adultos que no **son** violento**s**.

And indeed you can say

> Tratamiento basado en la intervención **para** jóvenes adultos no violentos.